# How to lock object face a certain distance away from another object face?

Tags: modeling, objects, constraints

I tried searching for this on google but I came up empty. I want to know how to lock the object 2 5 inches away from the corner of object 1? I want it to stay 5 inches away even if I re-scale.

How do I lock "cube 2" 5 inches away from the edge of object 1?

Here is an image of what I want to do:

[image: here is an image of what I want to do:]

**EDIT:**
I want to offset "cube 2" 5 inches away from the bottom right vertex of "cube 1" no matter where "cube 1" is?

This is so if I move or scale "cube 1", "cube 2" would still be offset 5 inches from the bottom right vertex of "cube 1".

Comment: Is this about exact positioning? Do you want to parent cube2 to cube1 and move them around by maintaining the offset? Or simply lock the position of cube2 independently of cube1 (Properties Panel 'N' has  locks for the location transformation)

Comment: ya i want to maintain the offset from cube 1 not where it is on the grid

Answer (score 2):

Set object2 origin point to its right bottom corner and you are free to scale in object mode.

Select object2, go to edit mode, select right bottom vertex, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> > Cursor to selected.
Return to object mode <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> > Origin to 3D cursor.

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: @JuhaW it didnt work :( i want to offset "cube 2" 5 inches away from the bottom right vertex of "cube 1"

Answer (score 2):

There are always a few things you can do when trying to move things in exact increments.
the first is to enable increment snapping, noted by the magnet on the bottom of the 3D view-port.

[image]

Another way is to type the distance you want your object to move on your keyboard.

example. <kbd>G</kbd>><kbd>x</kbd>><kbd>1</kbd>

This will move your object one unit on the 'X' axis.

if you find you object does not line up with the grid <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>>'Selection to Grid' will realign your object to the nearest major intersection on the grid.

Hope this helps,

Vince

Comment: what if i want to offset "cube 2" 5 inches away from the bottom right vertex of "cube 1" no matter where "cube 1" is?

so if i move or scale "cube 1", "cube 2" would still be offset 5 inches from the bottom right vertex of "cube 1"

Comment: Parent cube two to cube one, then do as JuhaW said and change to origin. Either that or re-position the cubes each time you move it. If you want the cubes to move and scale uniformly, select both and press Ctrl+J